# Crawling within a pdf

Tags: pdf, ms-word

I'm developing a tool that searches the keyword entered by the user on a given site. My problem is, it searches the keyword only on html/web pages but not on the PDF/MS-Word files found on the site.

Can anyone suggest me some api/tool or provide the code that can search text from the given online PDF/MS-Word/Text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use [Antiword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiword) for word files.

`pdftotext` can be used for pdf-files.

Both commands available through apt: 
`sudo apt-get install xpdf-utils antiword`

Comment: But I don't want to download the file, I want to download only those files that have the keyword.

Means, I need to search in PDFs online and download only if the PDF contains that keyword (which user is searching).

Comment: Wow.. you honestly think you can search for a keyword in a file, without downloading the file?? The actual search would then obviously need to be done on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Developing in anything that runs on the JVM, you would probably do best using POI for MS Office document parsing and [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/), [JPedal](http://www.jpedal.org/) or [PDF Clown](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clown/) for parsing .pdfs.

For general indexing, you wont miss with [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) and [nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/).